# Json becomes undefined and unsure why

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a json feed which i'm currently using ajax to try and get the data displayed in a list format. I've never used a json feed before so had to learn alot from these forums.

At the moment the data is becoming undefined and not sure why. Now i know the json feed is across domain so need jsonp and a callback function as not one in url.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JSONP test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadgatewayJSON() {

$.ajaxSetup({ 
        global  : true, 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        jsonp   : 'callback',
        cache   : true,
        data: {eventTypeId:1}, 
        ajaxStart: function(){
            //$('#content').hasClass('loading');
        },
        complete: function(){ 
             //$('#content').removeClass('loading');
        }
        });

    $.ajax({

        url: '(my url for feed)',
                   success: function(data, status) { 
                        $('#content').empty();  
                        var numResults = data.length;
                        alert(data);
                        for (var i=0;i < numResults;i++) {                              
                            $('#content').append("<p>"+data[0].eventCount+"</p>");

                        };

                   },
                   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
                    alert("An error has occured");
                    alert(xhr.status); 
                    alert(xhr.responseText); 
                } 
        });
};
loadgatewayJSON();
</script>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just wondered if anyone can spot any errors i've done in the code for reasons why it is pulling up undefined. I really just want a list of the events. I hope someone here could help me.

**Update:**

I've got the feed pulling now but struggling to pull the data within the json feed.

The stuff i need to pull is

"name"
"startdate"
"enddate"
"eventtype"

I assumed it was:

```
$('#content').empty();  
var data = name.event;

alert(data);
for (var i=0;i < numResults;i++) {                              
$('#content').append('+data[0].events+');
```

Sadly all this pulls up is displaying +data[0].events+ load of times

update:

Thank for the fix for this one sadly nothing seems to be displayed so assume it is the wording i'm using.

```
    "status": "success",
        "eventCount": 681,
        "events": [
            {

"baseUrl":                 
"pageUrl":                                 
"name":                 
"owner":        
"startDate":                 
"startTime":                 
"endDate":                 
"endTime":
```

These are the feed ids and the information can be pulled using this code

```
success: function(data, status) { 
                    $('#content').empty();  
                    var data = data.name;
                    alert(data);
                    for (var i=0;i < data;i++) {                                
                        $('#content').append(data[0].events);

                    };
```

well 1 out of 2 issues fixed so yay. Today not been a waste at least. Thank you so much for your help as well :)

Comment: What does your url deliver? JSON or JSONP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is wrong,
`$('#content').append('+data[0].events+');`

You should have done 
`$('#content').append(data[0].events);`

`'+data[0].events+'` is treated as a string and the output is as expected.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed that one. Sadly still not pulling data but i guess i need to display the jsonp feed to explain abit more about whats in the feed.